# ARMA 2 - freeze every few seconds after long flashpoint session

Tags: arma-2

I have been playing flashpoint: Zargabad 1.23 ([armaholic](http://www.armaholic.com/page.php?id=11138)) with zeus ai (no ACE) and the game will start to hitch every 10 seconds or so after an extended session (40 kills maybe). Seems to be related to streaming in data but standing in one spot does not clear the issue. If I start a new session it will work fine again for a while.

DayZ does not have this issue and I didn't notice the problem on an older version of takistan (haven't played it in a while).

I am launching like this:

```
-nosplash -mod=@CBA;@CBA_A2;@CBA_OA;@zeu_AI -maxmem=4096
```

I have 8 GB ram i5-2500k with HD 6950.

Have tried

- using -maxmem=2047 (was original setting)
- Checked defrag status of C: drive and in steam cache (not fragmented)
- Increase the VRAM setting to high from medium.
- Updated to latest Catalyst
- Updated to latest CBA 0.8.6.182
- Changing affinity to one core. All it did was kill FPS.

What can I do to track this problem down?

Comment: Can we assume you've followed standard modding procedure and already disabled them one-by-one and in different combinations to find out what's causing the problem?

Comment: Disabling the mods (originally I thought they were required for flashpoint) breaks my save, so I have to start anew on another flashpoint map.

Since AI fixes from the mods make the enemy easier to deal with, I typically die sooner and do not make it to the time required for the problem to occur.

I am mainly looking for basic engine knowledge that I can apply to settings in case this is a core engine issue.